# php/sql joining tables with multiple fields

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to echo info from a database onto the webpage. The page is supposed to have a bunch of article publications which includes the title, authors, journal name (if applicable), date published. For example:

1. title of the article (with author 1, author 2, author 3), name of the journal, date published.

I've made two tables. One contains paper_id, author_id, paper_name, journal_name, date. Second one contains author_id, author_firstname, author_lastname.

The part I'm struggling with is outputting multiple authors. in the second table I have the following for first paper

author_id: 1
author_firstname: john
author_lastname: smith

author_id: 1
author_firstname: bob
author_lastname: thomas

I want to print this: Name of the paper (with john smith, bob thomas), journal name, date published.

I've tried joining author_id but it outputs the same paper twice (since i have two authors with id 1. I need suggestions as to how i should change the table or join it differently and what not. Any help will be appreciated, thanks. I'm also a beginner programmer

Comment: try using this, so that you can easily refer author for an article even if there is more than 1 or 2 authors:

author {author_id, ....<your_columns>}
article_author {article_id, author_id}
article {article_id, ...<your_columns>}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleieve the correct strategy is to use `GROUP_CONCAT` on each paper to obtain a comma separated list of authors.  As a note, each group in the query below having a given `paper_id` will *also* have the same values for `paper_name`, `journal_name` and `date`.  I include the columns other than `paper_id` so that they will be available in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT t1.paper_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t2.author_lastname, ', ', t2.author_firstname)
    SEPARATOR ' '),
    t1.journal_name, t1.date
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.author_id = t2.author_id
GROUP BY t1.paper_id, t1.paper_name, t1.journal_name, t1.date
```

Comment: Great! GROUP_CONCAT was exactly what I was looking for. I instead did CONCAT(t2.author_firstname, ' ', t2.author_lastname) as I wanted the following:

(with: john smith, bob thomas)

But it's doing the following:

(with john smith,bob thomas). Would you happen to know how I can add a space after the comma for multiple authors?

Comment: @Anon101 You can use the `SEPARATOR` parameter.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out (added ' ' in the front). Thank you very very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get your question but you have two tables, your query will be something like
   SELECT table1.id, columnnames FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id

Comment: RIght, but then how would I output it? I used the following: 
 $results = $db->query($sql);
 if ($results->num_rows) 
   while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
   echo "<li>", $row->paper_title, ", " $row->author_firstname, " ", $row->author_lastname,"</li><br>";
  }

Comment: after you've gotten the result and stored in a variable you can loop through it (This might be inefficient if it only returns a single row): 

        
    foreach($result as $row){
    $details[] = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'name' => $row['authorname'])
    }